# The inverse of x!

Tags: inverse, factorial

what is the inverse of a factorial function?
Its is not continuous but is modeled by the gamma function which is continuous so must have a inverse any research leads to the inverse gamma function that is a statistical distribution.
Is a inverse gamma and is so what is its definition?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624347/what-approximations-for-the-gamma-functions-inverse-appear-to-work-best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse factorial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998201/inverse-factorial-function)

Comment: Actually a better target is probably [Inverse of a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial)