# Inverse factorial function

Tags: factorial, inverse-function

I am wondering what is the inverse/opposite factorial function?
e.g $\text{inverse-factorial}*(6)=3$

Furthermore, I am intrigued to know the answer to:

$$a!=\pi $$
Find $a$.

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain this to me as I have found nowhere online with a good explanation of inverse factorial functions.
Thanks

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931846/does-the-gamma-function-have-an-inverse and http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-04/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want out of this? The most popular continuous version of factorial is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), but I don't know if "ask a calculator to approximate the solution to $\Gamma(x)=\pi$ and add $1$ to the answer" is the sort of thing you're looking for. For detailed strategies for approximating answers, maybe see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2739498/26369

Comment: No integer's factorial is $pi$ the only thing you have seen is $\frac{1}{2}!=\pi$ which is not true. See definition of Gamma function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function and see what happened when we put $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: also refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624347

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not a closed form or nice series for the inverse of the factorial (or Gamma function).

First obstacle is that the factorial has a local minimum at $x:\;\psi(x)=0\; \to \; x=0.4616..$, so , considering only positive values of the argument, that gives you two values for the inverse.

For an analysis of the problem please refer to [this](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/positivity2013/presentations/uchiyama.pdf) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2167v1) papers.
 A lighter look is given in [this other paper](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Factorial).

Finally an interesting approximated function is given [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

inverse functions are not well defined when it is not a $1:1$ function, and as there is a minimum where:
$$\Gamma'(z+1)=0$$
that is:
$$\int_0^\infty\partial_nt^ze^{-t}dt=0$$
which can be numerically estimated.